# R: Function "lowess" with NAs

Tags: r, na, smoothing

I am trying to use function "lowess" in base package to smooth a vector. The question is that the vector only has one NA value, but after smoothing by "lowess", 4 more NAs appear. I searched and some one suggest using "lowess" in package "gplots". I tried but got same results.

```
x1 <- c(NA, 19.93621, 17.64789, 17.78488, 17.11141, 18.4648, 19.62629, 17.5737, 17.48582, 18.76946, 19.57138, 19.62812, 2.982385, -0.1320513)
x2 <- lowess(x1)
x2
$x
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14

$y
[1]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA 18.988279 18.563642 18.407768 18.496699 17.922510 14.419999 10.861535  7.179754  3.145612
```

One way is to delete the NA in x1 so there is no NA after smoothing in x2$y.

```
x2 <- lowess(x1[-1])
x2
$x
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13

$y
 [1] 18.7079309 18.4481273 18.2491632 18.0847709 18.0946245 18.1282192 18.1497617 17.9298278 14.6441882 10.9465210  7.2635244  3.5247529 -0.3021372
```

But I just wonder why more NAs appear and is there an easier way? Thank you!

Comment: `lowess` does a local polynomial fit. If you have NA's in the local area of a point, those NA values will propagate to nearby values.

Answer (score 3):

`lowess` doesn't have any built-in `NA` handling

1. Probably the easiest thing to do long term is learn to use `loess` (whose options and settings are slightly different), which does deal with `NA` values (it has an `na.action` argument, like `lm` does, which by default should work much the way you want - however, in terms of syntax, `loess` works much more like `lm` than it does like `lowess`).
2. you can use `na.omit` directly on the arguments to `lowess`; that way you don't need to specifically identify which observations are omitted.

Comment: This seems great but with default parameter, `lowess` and `loess` give highly different results. Couldn't find out how to simply turn the former to the latter, could you guide me ?

Comment: This was a good question but alas no futher answers came up. Did you finally switch to `loess` or was `lowess` made to work the way you wanted? @Kacey